# How to add another domain to my chrooted named server

Tags: chroot, webserver, hostname, bind

Firstly I successfully have a domain working in a chroot named. There are files in `/var/named/chroot/var/named` called `mydomain.com.db` and `named.local` and `named.root`.

Also in `/var/named/chroot/etc` there is named.conf.

So mydomain.com works as both a hosted website and it has `ns1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com`.

Now what I want to do is only to add another domain `mydomain2.com` to this setup, however I'm having trouble to find tutorial articles on adding another domain. They mostly seem to focus on just the adding of the first domain.

I guess I have to create a new zone file and reference it in the `named.conf` but I don't know what the zone file should contain. I tried some trial and error guessing but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You add the second domain the same as the first -- create an entry in `/var/named/chroot/etc/bind/named.conf` referring to the new zone and its filename (easiest way is to copy over the line from `mydomain.com` and rename `mydomain` to `mydomain2` on all points of the line, then copy `mydomain.com.db` over to `mydomain2.com.db` and edit the new file to reflect the differences between `mydomain.com` and `mydomain2.com`

You *can* (and probably should) use the same NS and MX records for both domains.

ETA: The line in `named.comf` will look roughly like this:

```
zone "mydomain.com" { type master; file "mydomain.com.db"; };
```

A proper hosts file looks something like this:

```
;-----------------
;mydomain.com.db
;-----------------
@               IN      SOA     ns.mydomain.com.  postmaster.mydomain.com. (
                2011060701 ; serial
                28800      ; refresh
                7200       ; retry
                604800     ; expire
                86400)     ; minimum
;-----------------
; Nameserver(s) for the mydomain.com domain
;-----------------
@               IN      NS      ns.mydomain.com.
                IN      NS      ns2.mydomain.com.
                IN      NS      ns3.mydomain.com.
;-----------------
; Mail server(s) in the mydomain.com domain
;-----------------
@                   IN      MX      10      mail.mydomain.com.
                    IN      MX      20      some.fallback.server.
;-----------------
; Address record(s) for the mydomain.com domain 
;-----------------
localhost      IN      A               127.0.0.1
@              IN      A               12.34.56.78
www            IN      CNAME           mydomain.com.
mail           IN      A               34.21.75.68
pop3           IN      CNAME           mail
;-----------------
```

Note that any FQDN name HAS to end with a . or bind will implicitly tack `mydomain.com` after it. 
Lines preceded by a semicolon are comments.